# Ubuntu Single Sign On

Tags: single-sign-on

I wanted to backup my data before I proceeded to upgrading my Ubuntu, which requires you to login into the Ubuntu Single Sign On, however I am unable to recollect my password. Trying to use the forget password option, gives me an invalid email address. However if I use the same email  for registering as a new user, it gives me as a registered email address, preventing me for registering using the same email. Can you please help?

Comment: You can use offline or manual back-up solutions instead of whatever you're trying to use. If you keep your data on a separate partition from the system files, you don't even need to back them up, because they'll be left untouched during the system installation or upgrade.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry File services on ubuntu One is discontinued.
[image: Ubuntu One]

Send an email to isd-support asking for a password reset.

Then find somewhere else to upload your image, you can create an account at MEGA

https://mega.co.nz/#

Then create account. Or find somewhere else USB device DVDs for your backup.